# How to create a circuit that turns an LED on for a specific duration?

Tags: led

I want to have a circuit which turns on an LED for a minute when I push a button.

Something like a timed switch, but I don't know how to that and I can't find it on Google :-(

I know I could use something like an Arduino but I don´t want to use one because it is waste to use an Arduino for only that.

Comment: Do a Google search for "cd4060 timer"  One of the links that shows uo is <https://www.eleccircuit.com/4060-timer-circuit-project/> which should do what you want.

Comment: You can also use a PIC 12F508 or 12F675 but you would need to find or build a programmer unless you know someone who has one.

Comment: Thanks for your really fast help :-)) I searched again and found a solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Eu2JjaRIvM I looked on the Wiki-article and yes, I could do it that way but for my solution I have already all pieces at home. But thanks again for the really fast solution. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the 555 timer could do it. I think it can be used for durations such as one minute...esp. if you only need it be approximate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Monostable

Answer (score 0):

Any monostable multivibrator would do the job.